# Is there a good workaround to getting a calculated column to from one Sharepoint List (List B) copy to another Sharepoint List (List A)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have a Master Sharepoint List (List A) and a Secondary List (List B). I have a Calculated Value in List B that is simply the Sum of Column values.

How would I best get that data to the Master Sharepoint list? Both tables use a User Email as a primary key (in addition to the built in ID key for Sharepoint Lists).

Since I am much more visual than verbal....my Master List would ideally be pulling its List B Total Score directly from List B. See below:

Master List

| Email | Site | List B Total Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| demo@email.com | Mars | 30 |
| sample@email.com | Jupiter | 40 |

List B

| Email | Test 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 | Total Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| demo@email.com | 10 | 10 | 10 | 30 |
| sample@email.com | 10 | 10 | 20 | 40 |

I have tried browsing through here for a solution and have even been checking the MS forums for some insight. I may just be using the wrong terms to try and figure out how to perform this operation so any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you simply copy the Total scores from your list B to list A using the "Data View" mode?

Comment: If you're looking for a combined view instead of copying data from ListB to ListA, you can take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iahtFLEncu8) describing how to Link two lists using SharePoint Designer. I think, you could link on [Email] column and show desired fields in the view. It's old school, not verified in SPO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create a Microsoft flow to copy the calculated data to another list.

See following steps:

1. Add the trigger in Mater list(When an item is created or modified)， then use "Get items" action to get all items from ListB:

[image]

2.Use a loop action "Apply to each" to process a list of items, then add a compose to remove decimal points on calculated column:

```
int(items('Apply_to_each')?['Total_x0020_Score'])
```

[image]

3.Add condition action to check if email in ListB is equal to email in Master list:

[image]

4.If it is true, update the related column in Master list with Total Score composed value in List B:

[image]

Result:

[image]